# PHP - Displaying a $ statement inside array

Tags: php, string, wordpress

I have a statement `$latest_pollid` and would like to put this inside of an array that looks something like this:

```
array(
        'comment_status'    =>  'open',
        'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
        'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
        'post_name'         =>  $slug,
        'post_title'        =>  $pollq_question,
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'post_type'         =>  'post',
        'post_content'      =>   
    )
```

For the `post_content` item, I would like to set it to be as follows:
 `[poll id=$latest_pollid]` 
But I know that I can't mix these two as they are. Is there any way I can place the value from `$latest_pollid` in this statement? `'post_content' =>  '[poll id=xxxxxx]'`

Would using a **sprint** type string do this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `'post_content' =>  '[poll id=' . $latest_pollid . ']'`

Comment: what's wrong with this `'[poll id='.$latest_pollid.']'`..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
'post_content' => '[poll id=' . $latest_pollid . ']'
```

or

```
array(
        'comment_status'    =>  'open',
        'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
        'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
        'post_name'         =>  $slug,
        'post_title'        =>  $pollq_question,
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'post_type'         =>  'post',
        'post_content'      =>  '[poll id=' . $latest_pollid . ']'
    )
```